# max-series-per-database limit exceeded clarification needed / how to calculate number of series in use

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, influx-line-protocol

We recently started to encounter this error:

```
{"error":"partial write: max-series-per-database limit exceeded: (1000000) dropped=1"}
```

When writing metric data like this:

```
resque_job,environment=beta,billing_status=active-current,billing_active=active,instance_id=1103,instance_testmode=0,instance_staging=0,server_addr=RESQUE,database_host=db11.msp1.our-domain.com,admin_sso_key=_EMPTY_,admin_is_internal=_EMPTY_,queue_priority=default seconds_spent_job=0.20966601371765,number_in_batch=1 1649203450783000002
```

I know that Influx recommends you keep your series cardinality low, and our impression was that series cardinality would mean keeping *each tag individually* to a small number of values. e.g. we felt comfortable sending `instance_id=1103` as a tag, because we know that there will never be more than `2000` distinct `instance_id` tag values.

But after running into this error... I'm afraid maybe I was mistaken here. Do we actually need to keep the cardinality of *all possible combinations of all tags* low? e.g. do these two things count as *two separate series* towards the `1,000,000` default max, because the `instance_id` is different?

```
resque_job,environment=beta,billing_status=active-current,billing_active=active,instance_id=1111,instance_testmode=0,instance_staging=0,server_addr=RESQUE,database_host=db11.msp1.our-domain.com,admin_sso_key=_EMPTY_,admin_is_internal=_EMPTY_,queue_priority=default seconds_spent_job=0.20966601371765,number_in_batch=1 1649203450783000002

resque_job,environment=beta,billing_status=active-current,billing_active=active,instance_id=2222,instance_testmode=0,instance_staging=0,server_addr=RESQUE,database_host=db11.msp1.our-domain.com,admin_sso_key=_EMPTY_,admin_is_internal=_EMPTY_,queue_priority=default seconds_spent_job=0.20966601371765,number_in_batch=1 1649203450783000002
```

If those count as two separate series... then is there a better way to structure this data in Influx? `1,000,000` total seems like a *tiny* amount if each separate combination of tags is a separate series...

Does InfluxDB 2.x help with this?

Is there a better tool that can handle a large number of tags and not bump into limits like this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to figure out what data was not recorded. Update the max-series-per-database configuration to be more than 1M in order to stop dropping data.

This can be an indication that you are creating a lot of series. i saw some  [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/#don-t-have-too-many-series) on why that isn't great.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this answers any of the questions I have...?